# Hide/remove ListPreference from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, listpreference, preferencescreen

How can I remove ListPreference from PreferenceScreen at runtime?
Something like setVisibility(Visibility.GONE) on a parent row.

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    protected void onConfigurationChanged(ApplicationConfiguration config)
    {
        // ...
        if(config.actualAccounts.sie() < 1)
        {
             ListPreference p = (ListPreference) findPreference("account");
             p.setEnabled(false);
             // here I want to hide it at all
        }
        // ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb..

```
final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen(); 
// ...
if(config.actualAccounts.sie() < 1)
{
    preferenceScreen.removePreference((ListPreference) findPreference("account"));
}
```